# Pass zero in to Getopt::Std

Tags: perl, getopt

I am using `Getopt::Std` in a Perl script, and would like to pass in a zero as value. I am checking that values are set correctly using `unless()`. At the moment `unless()` is rejecting the value as being unset.

Is there a way to get `unless()` to accept zero as a valid value (any non-negative integer is valid).

This is probably perfeclty simple, but I've never touched Perl before a few days ago!

Rich

Comment: What do you mean by 'pass zero as a value'?  Is this a command line option - as in '`cmd -0`' (comparable to `xargs -0`)?  Or as one of the arguments to the `getopt` function from `Getopt::Std`?  As written, your question is not clear.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. I want to do `perl myScript -c 0` and `unless($opt_c)` to return true.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use `unless defined <SOMETHING>`  instead of `unless <SOMETHING>` , because zero is false in Perl.

Answer (score 4):

Perl 5 has [several false values](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Truth-and-Falsehood): `0`, `"0"`, `""`, `undef`, `()`.

It is important to note that some things may look like they should be false, but aren't.  For instance `0.0` is false because it is number that is equivalent to `0`, but `"0.0"` is not (the only strings which are false are the empty string (`""`) and `"0"`).

It also has the concept of definedness.  A variable that has a value (other than undef) assigned to it is said to be defined and will return true when tested with the [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) function.

Given that you want an argument to be a non-negative integer, it is probably better to test for that:

```
unless (defined $value and $value =~ /^[0-9]+$/) {
    #blah
}
```